# Any way to recover my gear from this bug?

Tags: dragon-age-origins-awakening

I recently ran into [this bug](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Silverite_Mine#Bugs) where my commander lost all his gear.  Unfortunately at the time, I progressed through the dungeon enough that my auto-saves all got overwritten, and my previous save is over 5 hours ago.

Is there any way, via cheating or otherwise, to get me back my gear?

This is for the PC version.

Comment: i would imagine you should be able to use the Dragon Age Toolset to modify your save and add the gear to it. don't ask me how though :-\

Comment: I'd like to ask you how, but since you asked me not to, I'll have to ask someone else

Comment: Console or PC??

Answer (score 2):

Option 1) use the console to give you items, using the mod "Runscript additem" (http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=1131)

Option 2) Get a save editor, and add the items yourself;

Option 3) Reequip, at Silverite Mine you probably don't have that much stuff yet, if doing it on a usual order.

Comment: got any links to a save editor?

Comment: http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Save_Game_Editing